# Проблемы с ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

Сижу мучаюсь не могу понять в чём проблема.
Я делаю веб блог на ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, изначально при создании проекта я не указал что нужны какие-либо модули для авторизации.
Я добавил их позже через контекстное меню проекта.
Но при нажатии на кнопки Register или Login ничего не происходит практически, только в url строке браузера изменяется на это *"https://localhost:7086/?area=Identity&page=%2FAccount%2FRegister"*, а по факту остается главная страница.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ковырял код но так ничего и не смог исправить.
Прикрепляю пару исходников:

**Program.cs**

```
using System.Reflection;
using WebApplication1.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Serilog;
using WebApplication1.Areas.Identity.Data;

// Add Logging

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateBootstrapLogger();


try
{
    Log.Information("Starting web host...");
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "SimpleBlog API",
            Description = "",
            TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
            Contact = new OpenApiContact
            {
                Name = "Contact",
                Url = new Uri("https://example.com/contact")
            },
            License = new OpenApiLicense
            {
                Name = "License",
                Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license")
            }
        });
        var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
    });

    builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<WebApplication1User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebApplication1Context>();
    
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApplication1ContextConnection");;
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<WebApplication1Context>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
    

    var app = builder.Build();
    
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Fatal(e,"Host terminated unexpectedly!");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SimpleBlog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebApplication1.styles.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/up_button.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">SimpleBlog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"> <i class="bi bi-house"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy"> <i class="bi bi-shield"></i> Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Index"> <i class="bi bi-sticky"></i> Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--<div class="col-9 text-end">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Create"> <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i> Create Post</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>-->
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial"/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="upBtn" title="Go to top">↑</button>

<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div id="footer" class="container">
        &copy; 2022 - SimpleBlog - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/up_button.js"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using WebApplication1.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<WebApplication1User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<WebApplication1User> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

**Register.cshtml**

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to register.</h3>
            <hr />
            @{
                if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See this <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">article
                            about setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**Register.cshtml.cs**

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebApplication1.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<WebApplication1User> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<WebApplication1User> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<WebApplication1User> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<WebApplication1User> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<WebApplication1User> userManager,
            IUserStore<WebApplication1User> userStore,
            SignInManager<WebApplication1User> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }


        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }

        private WebApplication1User CreateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance<WebApplication1User>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(WebApplication1User)}'. " +
                    $"Ensure that '{nameof(WebApplication1User)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                    $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
            }
        }

        private IUserEmailStore<WebApplication1User> GetEmailStore()
        {
            if (!_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
            }
            return (IUserEmailStore<WebApplication1User>)_userStore;
        }
    }
}
```

**Вот так выглядят катологи:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решил проблему :) 
Оказывается забыл добавить app.MapRazorPages(); 
Извините за беспокойство!

Answer (score 2):

P.S Решил проблему совершено случайно, когда листал официальную документацию Microsoft.

Я забыл добавить `app.MapRazorPages();` в **Program.cs**
Надеюсь мой глупый поступок кому-то в будущем спасет несколько часов свободного времени :)

[Документация Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)